# How to make request to rest session based api from chrome extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, django-rest-framework

I have django rest framework based app, where i am using session based authentication. All apis need session authentication to return results otherwise it will give 403.

App has login flow where user login and session is set under cookie and all apis authenticated after that.

Now i am building chrome extension for same app where i need to make one of the rest api call. since user is already logged in browser so i am assuming that i can make the api call from chrome extension. but when i make the api call from chrome extension its returning 403. I am using fetch to perform request.

I am new in developing chrome extension so i am not able to figure out how to authenticate api call from chrome extension since user is already logged in browser.

I tried ajax request and fetch request and also set the permission in manifest.json.

```
fetch(url, {
 credentials: 'include'
})
```

Comment: It's possible the auth cookies are session-only so they work only in the tab. Use devtools (or other tools like Fiddler) to compare the request made by your extension to the one from a normal web page (in its devtools console, maybe) where the user is authenticated.

Comment: Hmm, no i don't think so because once you authenticate you can directly call api in any other tab of browser. so this is definitely not only for that tab.

Comment: yeah in chrome extension there is no request headers basically no cookie being set while making request, and in browser the request headers set with appropriate cookie value

Comment: Try specifying `mode: 'cors'` in fetch options (and other values for the mode).

Comment: no its not worked again forbidden request, this is fetch request

```
fetch("https:/example.com/api/v1/" {
 credentials: 'include',
 mode: 'cors'
})
 .then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
 })
 .then(function(json) {
  console.log(json);
 });

```
and in manifest.json i added "permissions": ["https:/example.com"],